# Hierarchical structure of classes object with Incr Tcl

Tags: class, tcl, incr-tcl, itcl

I'm trying to implement a hierarchical structure of classes/subclasses **objects** such as:

```
|-- Class1                  # mainClass
|   |-- SubClassA           # subClass
|   `-- SubClassB           # subClass
`-- Class2                  # mainClass
    |-- SubClassA           # subClass
    `-- SubClassB           # subClass
```

The main point here is to be able to declare **different** subclasses having the **same name** in each main classes (and have their variables independant).

(Note: I'm talking here about hierarchy of classes **objects** created during execution, not about heritage of different classes.)

Quite not very familiar with some advanced aspects specific to Tcl (namespace, scope...), I tried the following code:

```
package require Itcl

itcl::class subClass {
  variable InternalVariable
  constructor {} {
    puts "($this)     Current namespace      : [namespace current]"
    puts "($this)     InternalVariable scope : [itcl::scope InternalVariable]"
  }
}

itcl::class mainClass {
  variable SubClassesList
  constructor {} {
    set SubClassesList {}
    puts "($this)     current namespace      : [namespace current]"
    puts "($this)     SubClassesList scope   : [itcl::scope SubClassesList]"
  }
  method newSubClass {argName} {
    lappend SubClassesList [subClass $argName]
    puts "($this)     SubClassesList         : {$SubClassesList}"
  }
}

# Create the two main classes
mainClass Class1
mainClass Class2

# Add some subclasses to Class1 and Class2
Class1 newSubClass SubClassA
Class1 newSubClass SubClassB
Class2 newSubClass SubClassC
Class2 newSubClass SubClassB
```

which produces an error when creating the second occurence of `SubClassB`:

```
(::Class1)     current namespace      : ::mainClass
(::Class1)     SubClassesList scope   : @itcl ::Class1 ::mainClass::SubClassesList
(::Class2)     current namespace      : ::mainClass
(::Class2)     SubClassesList scope   : @itcl ::Class2 ::mainClass::SubClassesList
(::mainClass::SubClassA)     Current namespace      : ::subClass
(::mainClass::SubClassA)     InternalVariable scope : @itcl ::mainClass::SubClassA ::subClass::InternalVariable
(::Class1)     SubClassesList         : {SubClassA}
(::mainClass::SubClassB)     Current namespace      : ::subClass
(::mainClass::SubClassB)     InternalVariable scope : @itcl ::mainClass::SubClassB ::subClass::InternalVariable
(::Class1)     SubClassesList         : {SubClassA SubClassB}
(::mainClass::SubClassC)     Current namespace      : ::subClass
(::mainClass::SubClassC)     InternalVariable scope : @itcl ::mainClass::SubClassC ::subClass::InternalVariable
(::Class2)     SubClassesList         : {SubClassC}
command "SubClassB" already exists in namespace "::mainClass"
```

I'm probably missing a point about classes namespaces because I do not understand how the variable `SubClassesList` can have two different scopes but the "same" namespace/name (from debug output).

I tried to create a new namespace in the `newSubClass` method but it did not resolve the problem and/or add some inextricable variables namespaces errors...

```
method newSubClass {argName} {
  set SubClassName "[namespace current]::[namespace tail $this]"
  puts "($this)     SubClassName           : $SubClassName"
  namespace eval $SubClassName "lappend SubClassesList [subClass $argName]"
  puts "($this)     SubClassesList         : {$SubClassesList}"
}
```

Any idea to perform such a thing ?

P-S: I used [incr Tcl] to implement classes in my project for compatibility reasons with existing environment but if someone thinks that an other OO implementation would be better/easier, please let me know...

---

#### EDIT :

Found a solution by using `namespace eval` + `namespace inscope` to create `subClass` objects in a new namespace corresponding to `mainClass` objects name:

```
itcl::class mainClass {
  variable SubClassesList
  constructor {} {
    set SubClassesList {}
    puts "($this)     current namespace      : [namespace current]"
    puts "($this)     SubClassesList scope   : [itcl::scope SubClassesList]"
    # Create a new namespace corresponding to class name
    namespace eval $this {}
  }
  method newSubClass {argName} {
    # Create the subClass object in the $this namespace
    lappend SubClassesList [namespace inscope $this subClass $argName]
    puts "($this)     SubClassesList         : {$SubClassesList}"
  }
}
```

Comment: I you need portability, I suggest using snit or stooop. They are both written in pure Tcl and should run everywhere where Tcl runs.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confused between a *class* and an *object*: Class is a blue print, or template, for creating objects. In your example:

- `mainClass` and `subClass` are classes
- `Class1`, `Class2`, `SubClassA`, `SubClassB`, and `SubClassC` are objects, AKA instances of classes

In Itcl, each class has its own namespace, for example, class `mainClass` owns a namespace called `::mainClass` -- you see this evidence in the output your code:

```
(::Class1)     current namespace      : ::mainClass
^^^^^^^^^^
```

Furthermore, each object has its own namespace: ::::. For example,  the `SubClassB` object owns the namespace `::mainClass:SubClass`:

```
(::mainClass::SubClassB)     InternalVariable scope : @itcl ::mainClass::SubClassB ::subClass::InternalVariable
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That means, you cannot have have two objects that share the same name--that's the error you are getting. If you still want to example to work, use `#auto` for object name:

```
method newSubClass {argName} {
    lappend SubClassesList [subClass #auto] ;# <=== Use automatic naming
    puts "($this)     SubClassesList         : {$SubClassesList}"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I think I understand the point and the problem.

Comment: The `#auto` solution works but is a problem because I must know each `subClass` objects names before execution (too long to explain why here...).

A question then:

Is it possible to create the object `SubClassA` in a new namespace called for example `::Class1` and how?

Comment: OK, found an alternative solution with `namespace eval` + `namespace inscope` (post edited).
Don't know if it is a very clean solution but it seems to fits to my needs.
Thanks again for your explanations.